# UITextField resize width like safari on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, resize, uitextfield, width

How do I resize the UITextField when clicked with, like the search bar in mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know the answer, so I made you a little demo project.

http://github.com/st3fan/iphone-experiments/tree/master/Miscellaneous/ResizingTextField/

Comment: Thanks works flawlessly. I also assume this works for all uiviews